# can not create /dev/shm

Tags: devices, udev, fstab, shared-memory

I need to create `/dev/shm` on an embedded ARM system. 
From "[Installed The Latest Changes to Current and......](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/installed-the-latest-changes-to-current-and-844279/page4.html#post4159848)".

I see that it can be created with `mkdir /lib/udev/devices/shm`, but I'm wondering what is supposed to be at that location? The only directory I have at that location is `/lib/modules/`, there's no `devices/` or anything.

So I went ahead and just created them, empty directories. I then added:

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults       0 0
```

to my `/etc/fstab` and I didn't add an `mtab` entry, since I don't have an `/etc/mtab`. I then rebooted and now, there's still no `/dev/shm` device.

Any ideas how I get that device?

#### EDIT #1

Oh, and a `mount -a` (after a reboot) results in:

```
# mount -a
mount: mounting tmpfs on /dev/shm failed: No such file or directory`
```

Comment: You may be interested in the [Embedded systems site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design?referrer=2lF5gAel4peFRGSmvGLajg2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An embedded system may have a static `/dev`, rather than use udev to populate it. If you don't have `/lib/udev`, then presumably your system isn't running udev. In that case, you need to create `/dev/shm` on the root filesystem.

If the root filesystem is an initramfs, rebuild your initramfs with an extra line in the initramfs description file:

```
dir /dev 755 0 0
dir /dev/shm 755 0 0
…
```

If the root filesystem is an on-disk filesystem, just create the directory.

```
# mkdir /dev/shm
```